# How can I have a player be "on" two teams at a time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that the question might be phrased in a way that confuses people, so please suggest edits.

My dilemma is this: I have teams, set up with a scoreboard. These are Winner and Player, for a PvP minigame in development.

I also want to add classes, however. My way of doing this now would be to create a team like classUnlocked and put players onto it as they unlock a certain class.

Sadly, minecraft can only have a player be on one team at once. How would I keep the Winner/Player system and also add Classes that can be permanently unlocked for a specific group of players? (the ones who purchased it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use the right tool for the job

Scoreboard teams have some unique features in that any player can only be in one team, they have special treatment for `/spreadplayers` and a variety of options regarding visibility and other things.

None of what you are doing truly seems to require teams at all. Why is there a player team? Why is there a Winner team? As in: In how far do you benefit from making them *teams* rather than something else (see below). The same is true for your class unlocks.

#### Use scoreboard objectives or tags instead

Both serve the purpose of adding an arbitarily high amount of properties to a player. Using objectives for this is a bit strange, however, which is the primary reason why Mojang introduced scoreboard tags in Minecraft 1.9.

If you are using 1.9 and can therefore use tags, it's as simple as

```
scoreboard players tag <targetSelector> add unlockKnight
```

You can now use `@a[tag=unlockKnight]` or `@a[tag=!unlockKnight]` as selectors in your other commands.

Note that you can't select a player by two tags at once, i.e. `@a[tag=unlockKnight,tag=Winner]` doesn't work. If such double-tagging is necessary for whatever reason, I suggest you turn one of the tags into an objective instead.

In 1.8, you can create a dummy-type objective for every unlock and set it to 1 for players who did unlock it.

Comment: Right. So you know, I'm relatively new to scoreboard commands, but I have quite a bit of experience with command blocks in general. The Players team represents people opted in to a game, and I have a block checking how many people there are on the Player team, then when there is one left transferring them to the winner team. I'm on 1.8, so I'm assuming I have to use the dummy objective, right? Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: @Wombatorks yeah, on 1.8, using a dummy objective for the class unlocks would be best, although they are a slight hassle to set up.

Comment: That's OK, I think I can handle it ;D. Again, thanks  alot for your help.

Comment: In 1.13, use `/tag ...` instead of `/scoreboard players tag ...`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add teams that have the same privileges and functions of the two teams(eg. PlayerWinner) and add corresponding players to those teams. This would be the closest thing I can think of to be on two teams at once.